# Copy to clipboard in bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, copy, clipboard

I want to add a "copy to clipboard" button on my website. The site uses the Bootstrap 3 framework. I want my button to work similarly to the "Copy to Clipboard" button used here: http://twitterbootstrapbuttons.w3masters.nl/

I tried to incorporate this code: http://jsfiddle.net/T2uXr/, but I have had no success with it.

Javascript:

```
$("a.copy").on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).each(function () {
  $(this).zclip({
    path: 'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function() {
      return $(this).data('copy');
    }
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 20px
}
```

HTML

```
<hr />

<h5>These copy to clipboard links are working...</h5>

<p><a href="#" data-copy="http://test.one.com/" class="copy">Copy Original Link</a></p>

<p><a href="#" data-copy="http://test.two.com/" class="copy">Copy Medium Link</a></p>

<p><a href="#" data-copy="http://test.three.com/" class="copy">Copy Web Link</a></p>

<hr />

<h5>If I put these links inside the bootstrap dropdown, they stop working...</h5>

<div class="btn-group">
                  <a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    View copy clipboard links
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" data-copy="http://test.one.com/" class="copy">Copy Original Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-copy="http://test.two.com/" class="copy">Copy Medium Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-copy="http://test.three.com/" class="copy">Copy Web Link</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="mailto:" title="Email URL Links">Email URL Link</a></li>
                  </ul>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how I should add this to a button on my Bootstrap 3 site? Or are there any other good alternatives?

Thanks! :)

Comment: There is no magic to it, you just include the script on your page, and every link with class `copy` will then be a clipboard copy link. Of course you also have to include the `zclip` library and you can change the selector to choose any other element(s).

Comment: use code snippets

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I have fixed the issue while working on it till late night 4:00 AM and posting my issue ([click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641671/not-able-to-find-this-objects-parent-in-zeroclipboard-v2-1-6-plugin) to see), hope this will help some one to not burn his night :) I tried to do how Bootstrap current website does for copying it's code, but Bootstrap is currently using old zeroClipboard Plugin. I have tried to make same as Bootstrap did but with latest zeroClipboard (as of now).

**HTML:** Note how I have not added all the code in one line, do not bring `pre` & `code` in second line or indent it to make code look good else the extra intend will copied to clip board.

```
<div class="highlight"><pre><code>Some code/text goes here</code></pre></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* ZeroClipboard styles */

.zero-clipboard {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
.btn-clipboard {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #777;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e8;
    border-radius: 0 4px 0 4px;
}
.btn-clipboard-hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #563d7c;
    border-color: #563d7c;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .zero-clipboard {
        display: block;
    }
    .zero-clipboard .btn-clipboard {
        top: -16px;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }
}
```

**JavaScript:** place `ZeroClipboard.swf` where the JS file is.

```
// Config ZeroClipboard
ZeroClipboard.config({
    hoverClass: 'btn-clipboard-hover'
})

// Insert copy to clipboard button before .highlight
$('.highlight').each(function () {
    var btnHtml = '<div class="zero-clipboard"><span class="btn-clipboard">Copy</span></div>';
    $(this).before(btnHtml)
});

var zeroClipboard = new ZeroClipboard($('.btn-clipboard'));
var htmlBridge = $('#global-zeroclipboard-html-bridge');

// Handlers for ZeroClipboard
zeroClipboard.on('ready', function (event) {
    htmlBridge
        .data('placement', 'top')
        .attr('title', 'Copy to clipboard')
        .tooltip();

    // Copy to clipboard
    zeroClipboard.on('copy', function (event) {
        var highlight = $(event.target).parent().nextAll('.highlight').first();
        event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", highlight.text())
    });

    // Notify copy success and reset tooltip title
    zeroClipboard.on('aftercopy', function () {
        htmlBridge
            .attr('title', 'Copied!')
            .tooltip('fixTitle')
            .tooltip('show')
            .attr('title', 'Copy to clipboard')
            .tooltip('fixTitle')
    });
});

// Notify copy failure
zeroClipboard.on('error', function () {
    ZeroClipboard.destroy();
    htmlBridge
        .attr('title', 'Flash required')
        .tooltip('fixTitle')
        .tooltip('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and also your jsfiddle code works correctly. I tried it in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox on Mac OS X and they all worked. As your code requires Flash, make sure to have Flash installed and enabled.