# Not able to find $(this) object's parent in zeroClipboard (v2.1.6) plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

**Got the answer with the help of @LanderVanBreda**

```
zeroClipboard.on('copy', function (event) {
    var highlight = $(event.target).parent().nextAll('.highlight').first()
    event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", highlight.text())
});
```

**Question was:**

The Code is almost working but got stuck at the final stage while copying the text to clipboard.

There is `$(this)` object but it's not working. I just want to make the below line of code work.

```
zeroClipboard.on('copy', function (event) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('someClass');
});
```

Here is the actual HTML:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active">
        <div class="highlight mb-0">
        <pre><code>Some vpaid code </code></pre>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane">
        <div class="highlight mb-0">
        <pre><code>Some mraid code</code></pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is how Browser output the HTML using zeroClipboard

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active">
        <div class="zero-clipboard"><span class="btn-clipboard">Copy</span></div>
        <div class="highlight mb-0">
        <pre><code>Some VPAID code </code></pre>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane">
        <div class="zero-clipboard"><span class="btn-clipboard">Copy</span></div>
        <div class="highlight mb-0">
        <pre><code>Some MRAID code</code></pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is JavaScript:

```
// Config ZeroClipboard
ZeroClipboard.config({
    hoverClass: 'btn-clipboard-hover'
})

// Insert copy to clipboard button before .highlight
$('.highlight').each(function () {
    var btnHtml = '<div class="zero-clipboard"><span class="btn-clipboard">Copy</span></div>'
    $(this).before(btnHtml)
});

var zeroClipboard = new ZeroClipboard($('.btn-clipboard'));
var htmlBridge = $('#global-zeroclipboard-html-bridge');

// Handlers for ZeroClipboard
zeroClipboard.on('ready', function (event) {
    htmlBridge
        .data('placement', 'top')
        .attr('title', 'Copy to clipboard')
        .tooltip();

    // Copy to clipboard
    zeroClipboard.on('copy', function (event) {
        var highlight = $(this).parent().nextAll('.highlight').first()
        event.setData(highlight.text())
    });

    // Notify copy success and reset tooltip title
    zeroClipboard.on('aftercopy', function () {
        htmlBridge
            .attr('title', 'Copied!')
            .tooltip('fixTitle')
            .tooltip('show')
            .attr('title', 'Copy to clipboard')
            .tooltip('fixTitle')
    });
});

// Notify copy failure
zeroClipboard.on('error', function () {
    ZeroClipboard.destroy();
    htmlBridge
        .attr('title', 'Flash required')
        .tooltip('fixTitle')
        .tooltip('show');
});
```

Comment: What happened? What error message(s) did you get in the console?

Comment: @syed 'this' will probably not be pointing to the dom object inside the event. You did use 'event.target' in your code so you could do $(event.target) instead of $(this) I think.

Comment: @LanderVanBreda I did the changes as you said and it worked, thanks :) you can mention this as answer rather comment, I will mark it as accepted answer. Just for your information - **$(this)** was working in earlier version of zeroClipboard, you can see that working in Bootstrap's current website. It's some how not working in latest version of zeroClipboard but now it's working with **$(event.target)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting it as an answer :

Because the this is used inside an event we can never know where 'this' refers to. I'm always scared of 'this'.

So solvable by :

```
$(event.target)
```

Instead of

```
$(this)
```